# How to send commands to a set of headphones via USB?

Tags: usb, audio, headphones

I recently bought the Edifier W820NB Plus headphones, and they're great. However, there's one major problem: the software.

The only software these headphones have is the Android Edifier app (which BTW tracks you and is full of bloatware). But I also want to use these headphones for my PC. Since my PC doesn't have Bluetooth, I decided to connect the headphones via USB-C.

There is only one issue: By default, the button on the side of the headphones can only switch between noise cancellation on and ambient sound; there is no way to just turn off noise cancellation. You can change that in the Edifier app, but as soon as you connect the headphones to power, this setting resets. And, since there isn't any official Edifier app for PC, I'm unable to use these headphones without noise cancellation (or ambient sound mode).

Is there any script/command that would allow me to turn off noise cancellation via USB-C, or maybe there is a way to prevent the reset of an option that adds the ability to turn off noise cancellation via the button? I tried doing it myself, but since I'm not a programmer, I just don't know how.

---

**Edit**: There is a guy on GitHub, [glpnk](https://github.com/glpnk), who managed to map most inputs of W820NB using live Wireshark capture and triggering specific functions of the app in real-time. Unfortunately, I can't find any easy way to translate Bluetooth inputs to USB.

I contacted him, and he was able to find a workaround to my problem: While connected to the PC via USB, you can use BLE to turn off ANC. It's very far from ideal, but the problem seems very hard, and I don't expect to find any better way. It's a shame that edifier doesn't care about its customers enough to make good software for Android and any software at all for PC.